# User search field temporarily enlarged while waiting for results

Tags: bug, design, users

On the [user list page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/), there's a search field, which temporarily enlarges while the page is loading results. This leads to a strange animation, especially visible on slower connections. Here is an example, slightly slowed down:

[image]

There might be more search fields with the same behaviour, though a similar one on the [tag list page](/tags) seems to work fine.